# The matrix diagonalizable coefficients in a field of characteristic different from $2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I read a property that I did not understand:

> Let $M\in GL(2,\mathbb{F}_3)$ the matrix such that $M= I_2$ or $M^2=I_2$. As it has **coefficients in a field of characteristic different from $2$**, it is diagonalizable.

Is it a theorem? Can you help me prove this result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M=I_2$ then $M$ is already diagonal.  Same if $M = -I_2$.  If $M^2 = I_2$ with $M \ne \pm I_2$ (so that no linear polynomial annihilates $M$) then $p(M) = M^2 - I_2 = (M-I)(M+I) = 0$ so $p(x) = (x-1)(x+1)$ is the minimal polynomial of $M$, and in a field of characteristic different from 2, the two factors $x-1$ and $x+1$ are distinct.  This implies that $M$ is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

If not already diagonal, the matrix has trace zero.

When the characteristic is not two, we have $2=1+1 \neq 0$

$$
\frac{1}{2} \; 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2&b\\
0&1\\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&b\\
0&-1\\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&-b\\
0&2\\
\end{array}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1&0\\
0&-1\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

For the next one, we need $a^2 + bc = 1 \; .$

$$
- \frac{1}{2c} \;
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
c&-1-a\\
-c&a-1\\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a&b\\
c&-a\\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
a-1&a+1\\
-c&c\\
\end{array}
\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
-1&0\\
0&1\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$